# Splitting Lists elements further

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a number of .txt files with varying numbers of columns (but always the same number of elements in each.

```
<1,1,1,1,1,>
<1,2,1,2,1,>
<2,3,2,3,2,>
<4,2,4,2,4,>
```

Since this is saved as a .txt file when I split by

```
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

I get

```
['<1,1,1,1,1,>', '<1,2,1,2,1,>', '<2,3,2,3,2,>', '<4,2,4,2,4,>']
```

Is there a simple way to access each of the elements within the list (ie individual numbers so I can output them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following:

```
lines = [line.strip('<>,\n').split(',') for line in f]
```

It will return a list of lists containing the numbers as strings:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
 ['1', '2', '1', '2', '1'], 
 ['2', '3', '2', '3', '2'], 
 ['4', '2', '4', '2', '4']]
```

If you want the numbers as integers instead you can call [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) after splitting a line:

```
lines = [map(int, line.strip('<>,\n').split(',')) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help niemmi, I do want to convert it into integers but currently Im having an issue in that when I run the code there are some unwanted characters such as the following:                               [[''], ['1'], [''], ['1'], [''], ['1'], [''], ['1'], [''], ['1'], [''], [''], ['\n'] for each line,Is there a way to strip the [''] and ['\n'] terms?

Comment: I had forgotten to strip the `\n` in the code examples. I modified the response and it should work now if the file contents are exactly the same as in the question.

Comment: Im still having issues with removing all the [''] terms inbetween each  number, this is stopping me using the map function to use the string as integers as I hoped, is it possible to do this within line.strip? I have tried but got an error

Comment: The input in the question doesn't have any `"` characters in it but assuming there are some in the real file you could do `str.replace` to remove them: `line.replace('"', '').strip('<>,\n').split(',')`

Comment: The issue is that there are none in the original file, it is exactly as above and I am struggling to get rid on the [''] (this is two individual 's not a single quotation mark) using the above line.replace('"', '').strip('<>,\n').split(',') because 'list' object has no attribute replace

Comment: I tried saving the data in question to a file called `test.txt`, then doing `f = open('test.txt')` followed by the last code line in my original answer. It produces the output as integers without problems. If you're using Python 3.x instead of 2.7 then it needs to be altered a bit but it still shouldn't show empty strings in the output.

Answer (score 0):

from ast import literal_eval

Once you have done `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]` you could do this:

```
linelist = []
for line in lines:
    linelist.append( literal_eval( line.replace( "<", "[" ).replace( ">", "]" ) ) )
```

This will create a list of lists. For the example you have provided, you'll get some thing similar to:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2], [4, 2, 4, 2, 4]]
```

You can use this for further processing.

Or directly do:

```
lines = [ literal_eval( line.rstrip('\n').replace( "<", "[" ).replace( ">", "]" ) ) for line in f]
```

The result will be the same.

Comment: There is a certain elegance to doing this. But using `eval` on untrusted input is *not* a good idea. Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

Comment: You are quite right. Perhaps I should have used `map` as [niemmi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5043793/niemmi) used. I'll edit it as per you suggestion.